# Is a compiler allowed to add functions to standard headers?

Tags: c, header, c99, standards

Is a C compiler allowed to add functions to standard headers and still conform to the C standard?

I read this somewhere, but I can't find any reference in the standard, except in annex J.5:

> The inclusion of any extension that may cause a strictly conforming
>   program to become invalid renders an implementation nonconforming.
>   Examples of such extensions are new keywords, **extra library functions
>   declared in standard headers**, or predefined macros with names that do
>   not begin with an underscore.

However, Annex J is informative and not normative... so it isn't helping.

So I wonder if it is okay or not for a conforming compiler to add additional functions in standard headers?

For example, lets say it adds non-standard itoa to stdlib.h.

Comment: I believe that yes; and I think it is common practice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In 4. "Conformance" §6, there is:

> A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional
>   library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming
>   program.

with the immediate conclusion in a footnote:

> This implies that a conforming implementation reserves no identifiers other than those explicitly
>   reserved in this International Standard.

The reserved identifiers are described in 7.1.3. Basically, it is everything starting with an underscore and everything explicitly listed as used for the standard libraries.

So, yes the compiler is allowed to add extensions. But they have to have a name starting with an underscore or one of the prefixes reserved for libraries.

`itoa` is not a reserved identifier and a compiler defining it in a standard header is not conforming.

Comment: I read that too, but I don't think foot notes are normative in ISO standards?

Comment: They don't have to have a name that starts with an underscore. In fact, identifiers starting with an underscore are more strictly regulated than identifiers not starting with an underscore (see 7.1.3 for an overview of reserved identifiers).

Comment: @Lundin: then ignore the footnote totally and think about what identifiers you _could_ add that wouldn't break a conforming program. Since conforming programs are allowed to create _any_ identifier that isn't already defined by the standard (with the exception of underscrore ones which are reserved for an implementation), the non-footnote (normative) bit is enough to answer your question.

Comment: @Lundin, @paxdiablo, there are other identifiers that are reserved by the standard, e.g all starting with `str`, IIRC.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: You have it backwards. An **application** is restricted from using identifiers beginning with an underscore in certain cases, but this is because they're reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @Jens: `str` is only reserved if `string.h` is included, and even then I believe it's only when followed by a lowercase letter (e.g. `str_` is not reserved) but I forget the details...

Comment: Thus, a compiler is allowed to add `strfoo` to standard header `<string.h>` - which answers the original question.

Comment: @R. : I was referring to the identifiers reserved for future library directions. They don't start with an underscore, but can still be used for extensions (afaik).
On the other hand, I mistakenly thought that identifiers starting with two underscores (or an underscore and an uppercase letter) were reserved for a more limited use, prompting my statement about the "more strict regulation". I stand corrected on that :)

Comment: So in other words, a compiler is only allowed to put things in a standard header that may be included in the standard in the future? Such as the reserved identifiers in 7.1.3 and the future language extensions 7.26? If they try to add anything beyond that (such as itoa), they are not conforming?

Comment: @Lundin: yes. Because the compiler would otherwise break programs using that identifiers themselves.

Comment: @R.., you are right for the lowercase letter, but wrong that they are
only reserved when the header is included, I think. It says *"All external
names described below are reserved no matter what headers are included by the program"*

Comment: Well they're always reserved as external names, but can still be used for macro names, functions and variables with static linkage, etc. as long as `string.h` is not included.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Would there be any problem with a compiler including some new functions in a header if they were marked with a `#pragma` that indicated to the compiler that user code should be allowed to define them and have such definition take precedence over the ones in the headers?

Answer (score 5):

In "7.26 Future library directions" you have a list of the identifiers that may be added to the standard headers, this includes identifiers starting with `str` or `mem`, macros starting with `E` and stuff like that.

Other than that, implementations are restricted to the generic names as reserved in "7.1.3 Reserved identifiers".

Comment: (+1) but ... identifiers beginning with `str` **and a lowercase letter**.

Comment: @undur_gongor, right, so `strip` and `isvalid` are reserved, but `str` , `strIP` and `is_valid` aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers for embedded systems regularly add functions and macros to standard headers, usually to make a special processor feature available for use.

If I read the standard correctly, they can do so without sacrificing conformity if they *do use* names specified as reserved by the standard. Since a conforming program may use any non-reserved name as a variable or a function name, using such a non-reserved name as an addition to a standard header would break a conforming program.

In practice, however, the compiler writers usually do not care too much. They will at most provide a list of elements defined for the system you may not use if you want your program to work with their implementation.

Comment: In practice, most compilers do not fully conform to the C standard (either C90 or C99) by default.  But most of them do have an option, or a set of options, that causes them to (attempt to) be fully conforming.  For example, `gcc -ansi -pedantic ...` or `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic ...`.  Note that gcc's C99 conformance is [not yet 100%](http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html).