# getchar_unlocked() implicit declaration in C99

Tags: c, c99

Using `getchar_unlocked` and compiling with `--std=c99` flag gives warningas follows-

> warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getchar_unlocked’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Does not give any warning if compiled without flag.Is there any way to work around with it ?

Comment: `--std=c99` is a strict mode, you might look into using `--std=gnu99` instead. Don't have the energy to try, but someone might :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, yes that should work, when one wants to use an extension of the C standard, namely POSIX, one should not restrict the compiler to bare C99. Even better would be to switch to `gnu11`, which seems to be the default for newer gcc versions, anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from C99 you must have a visible function prototype before calling a function. While the earlier C standard would just stupidly assume that any function unknown to the compiler has the format `int func (params)`, which in turn would cause severe bugs most of the time.

Properly declare a prototype for `getchar_unlocked` and the bug will go away.

Note that there is no such function present in any standard library. It seems you might have to include some non-standard library for the compiler to find the function.

Comment: this is not quite true. The function prototype type exists in stdio.h but is not visible in ['bare'] ansii C. As the function is from the posix definitions, so must have one of the following #defined in the source code: 
`POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE` 
--or-- select a `gcc` option -std=xxx that includes the posix functions like `-std=gnu99`

Answer (score 3):

`_unlocked` versions of `get...` functions are POSIX extensions. They are not part of the standard functions of C99. The full list of `get...` functions is given in 7.19.1.5: `getwc`, `getwchar`, `getc`, `getchar`, and `gets` (deprecated).

When the function is not on this list, C99-compliant compiler must warn you that your program may not compile with other C99-compliant compilers.

Comment: Rather, a conforming compiler is not allowed to freely dump any non-standard crap in standard library headers. They have to follow [naming conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270324/is-a-compiler-allowed-to-add-functions-to-standard-headers), they can't give a function a name like `getchar_unlocked` and put it in stdio.h. Apparently yet another conflict between standard C and the dysfunctional POSIX standard.

Comment: @Lundin, why would that be a conflict? POSIX extends the C standard, that's all, it says so clearly. And to use it, you have to tell the compiler that you want it. `-std=c99` tells exactly the contrary, that you want pure C99 and no extensions.

Comment: @JensGustedt POSIX is supposed to be a standard for operative system APIs. It shouldn't be concerned with meddling with the standard of a programming language. There is no reason for it to invoke non-standard behavior. It could as well peacefully co-exist with C like any other 3rd party library, but no, that would have been too smart... It all boils down to C and Unix being heavily entwined in each other from the start, and POSIX originating from *nix. Rather than making a standard suitable for any OS, they made a standard stating "do as it is done in Unix".

Answer (score 1):

Dialect selection options like `-ansi` and `-std=c99` cause the compiler to define certain macros (in addition to altering the accepted dialect).

Library header files react to those macros.

Precisely how they react is quite system-dependent (the compiler doesn't provide a C library), but a common behavior you can broadly expect is that if you use one of these flags alone (without any other "feature selection macro"), it has the effect of hiding the declarations of functions, macros and other global symbols which are not in the specified ISO C dialect.

ISO C knows nothing about `getchar_unlocked`. The presence of such a declaration in `<stdio.h>` (normally an ISO C header) is a POSIX extension, which is basically nonconforming, since `getchar_unlocked` is an identifier that strictly conforming C programs can use, even if they include `<stdio.h>`. When you use `-ansi` or `-std=c99`, the `<stdio.h>` header listens up and whips itself into ISO-C-conforming shape, hiding such extensions.

On well-behaved POSIX systems, you can request that you want an ISO C dialect **and** that you want certain rudimentary 1990-ish POSIX features to be visible in header files, for instance like this:

```
gcc -std=c99 -D_POSIX_SOURCE ...
               ^^^^^ "feature selection macro"
```

There is a whole science to these feature selection macros, too broad for this question and answer; some forms of them have values, like `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500`.  `_POSIX_SOURCE` doesn't need an argument; it is just defined or not, but `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is numeric.

I just checked glibc and Cygwin: on both, `_POSIX_SOURCE` is enough to reveal the `getchar_unlocked` declaration. It is quite old, dating back to POSIX.1 1996.

Beware: on some systems,  multiple feature selection macros don't play along reasonably; they give you a set intersection rather than union, so that `-D_POSIX_SOURCE` and `-D_BSD_SOURCE` together end up meaning "Declare to me only those handful of functions that are specific to classic BSD that have been standardized in POSIX too", which means that next to nothing is declared.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar_unlocked` is not a C standard function.

Compiling it forcing `c99` standard does not support it natively.