# What's the meaning of "reserved for any use"?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, c-standard-library

NOTE: This is a [c](/questions/tagged/c) question, though I added [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) in case some C++ expert can provide a rationale or historical reason why C++ is using a different wording than C.

---

In the C standard library specification, we have this normative text, C17 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers (emphasis mine):

> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore **are always reserved for any use**.
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.

Now I keep reading answers on SO by various esteemed C experts, where they claim it is fine for a compiler or standard library to use identifiers with underscore + uppercase, or double underscore.

Doesn't "reserved for any use" mean reserved for *anyone* except future extensions to the C language itself? Meaning that the implementation is *not* allowed to use them.

While the second phrase above, regarding single leading underscore seems to be directed to the implementation?

In general, the C standard is written in a way that expects compiler vendors/library implementers to be the typical reader - not so much the application programmers.

Notably, C++ has a very different wording:

> - Each name that contains a double underscore (`__`) or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.11) **is reserved to the implementation for any use**.

(See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier))

Is this perhaps a mix-up between C and C++ and the languages are different here?

Comment: No namespace support in C.  That makes life difficult for everybody.  Including the ISO committee, they have to have a way to add an identifier without breaking the world.

Comment: I'd say "reserved for any use" is for the implementation and standard library usage. Certainly the implementors of the library are expected to know the standard versions well enough to know the reserved names for each, so there is no name clash. Maybe this is meant to be extended to other system libraries, e.g. POSIX or Windows. But yes, I think missing custom namespaces are one reason for this floppy wording. I sometimes wish they **would** break "the world" of legacy code. That could still be compiled with the version it was designed for - or reworked. It works for e.g. Python.

Comment: Please don't remove the C++ tag. The last part of the question is regarding the difference of C and C++, which would be interesting to know. I'll try to research this part further on my own, too.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the C standard, the meaning of the term "reserved" is defined by 7.1.3p2, immediately below the bullet list you are quoting:

> No other identifiers are reserved. If *the program* declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

Emphasis mine: reserved identifiers place a restriction on the *program*, not the implementation.  Thus, the common interpretation – reserved identifiers may be used by the implementation to any purpose – is correct for C.

I have not kept up with the C++ standard and no longer feel qualified to interpret it.

Comment: I read that part too but I think it's a bit far-fetched to say that this is the definition of the term "reserved identifier"? One may as well read it as 7.1.3 §1 being restrictions for the implementation and §2 for the program. I also wonder why C++ words this differently. Was it a clarification added by the C++ committee at some point (maybe someone had the same confusion as I), which didn't make it back to C?

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, I think it was just a *very* early clarification (already present in a 1994 draft). I'm surprised though to see that this change was made *before* the text was further updated to reserve each name that "contains a double underscore", I figured it would have been made as long as that paragraph had to be edited anyway.

Comment: @hvd That's interesting, maybe you could post a quote as an answer to the second part of the question? I only managed to dig as far as C++98 and there the correction was made. As for C, the text has always been the same, all the way back to C89 drafts.

Comment: @Lundin I do not have anything factual to support the idea that no change in meaning was intended beyond what this answer already states (namely, that in C e.g. `__foo` is also reserved for any use by the implementation), but if zwol would like to incorporate it into this answer, it's [this 1994 draft](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/wp/pdf/sep94/body.pdf), [lib.global.names]p3, which says "Each name that begins with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore (2.8) is reserved to the implementation for any use."

Comment: So... everything seems to indicate that "reserved for any use" is indeed meant to say "reserved for the implementation". In fact the C99 rationale clarifies this. I posted my own research as a separate answer.

Answer (score 17):

While the Standard is primarily written to guide implementers, it is written *as* a description of what makes a program well-formed, and what its effect is. That's because the basic *definition* of a standards-conforming compiler is one that does the correct thing for any standards-conforming program:

> A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the language and library
>   specified in this International Standard....A conforming
>   hosted implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program.

Read separately, this is *hugely* restrictive of extensions to a compiler. For instance, based solely on that clause, a compiler shouldn't get to define *any* of its own reserved words. After all, any given word a particular compiler might *want* to reserve, could nevertheless show up in a strictly conforming program, forcing the compiler's hand.

The standard goes on, however:

> A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional
>   library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming
>   program.

That's the key piece. Compiler extensions need to be written in such a way that they affect *nonconforming* programs (ones which contain undefined behavior, or which shouldn't even compile at all), allowing them to compile and do fun extra things.

So the purpose of defining "reserved identifiers", when the language doesn't actually *need* those identifiers for anything, is to give implementations some extra wiggle room by providing them with some things which make a program nonconforming. The reason a compiler can recognize, say, `__declspec` as part of a declaration is because putting `__declspec` into a declaration is otherwise illegal, so the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants!

The importance of "reserved for any use", therefore, is that it leaves no question about a compiler's power to treat such identifiers as having any meaning it cares to. Future compatibility is a comparatively distant concern.

The C++ standard works in a similar way, though it's a bit more explicit about the gambit:

> A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do
>   not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that
>   use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. **Having done so, however,
>   they can compile and execute such programs.**

I suspect the difference in wording is down to the C++ standard just being clearer about how extensions are meant to work. Nevertheless, nothing in the C standard precludes an implementation from doing the same thing. (And we all basically ignore the requirement that the compiler warn you every time you use `__declspec`.)

Comment: This is another, but related issue, I think: if compiler's are allowed to dump their non-standard stuff in standard headers, and if so, what they may name it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270324/is-a-compiler-allowed-to-add-functions-to-standard-headers

Comment: @Lundin I don't see that as particularly problematic: A program including a standard header doesn't by itself give the compiler the right to reserve extra identifiers, but a compiler may decide to only allow a particular nonstandard construct if a standard header is included. (Defining *standard* things in other headers, in contrast... not sure about that one.)

Answer (score 15):

Regarding the difference in wording in C versus C++, I'm posting my own little research here as reference:

- The early [K&R C 1st edition](https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition) has this text:

> ...names which are intended for use only by functions of the library begin with an underscore so they are less likely to collide with names in a user's program.

- K&R 2nd edition added an Appendix B which addresses the standard library, where we can read

> External identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved for use by the library, as are all
> other identifiers that begin with an underscore and an upper-case letter or another underscore.

- Early ANSI C drafts, as well as "C90" ISO 9899:1990, has the same text as in the current ISO standard.
- The earliest C++ drafts however, has a different text, as noted by @hvd, possibly a clarification of the C standard. From [DRAFT: 20 September 1994](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/wp/pdf/sep94/):

> 17.3.3.1.2 Global names
> ...
> Each name that begins with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore (2.8) is
> reserved to the implementation for any use

So apparently the wording "reserved for any use" was invented by the ANSI/ISO C90 committee, whereas the C++ committee some years later used a clearer wording, similar to the wording in the pre-standard K&R book.

---

The C99 rationale V5.10 says this below 7.1.3:

> Also reserved for the implementor are all external identifiers beginning with an underscore, and
> all other identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter or an underscore.
> This gives a name space for writing the numerous behind-the-scenes non-external macros and
> functions a library needs to do its job properly.

This makes the committee's intention quite clear: "reserved for any use" means "reserved for the implementor".

---

Also of note, the current C standard has the following normative text elsewhere, in 6.2.5:

> There may also be
> implementation-defined extended signed integer types. 38)

where the informative foot note 38 says:

> 38. Implementation-defined keywords shall have the form of an identifier reserved for any use as
>     described in 7.1.3.

Comment: Re: "'reserved for any use' means 'reserved for the implementor'": More precisely: "reserved" means "reserved to the implementation", i.e. "forbidden to program code". "Reserved for any use" means "forbidden to program code for any use".

Comment: This exact answer includes a quotation with the phrase "is reserved to the implementation for any use". Surely you're not arguing that that means "reserved to the implementation for the implementor"?

Comment: @ruakh Oh, your comment is some sort of summary of the answer? I read it as an attempt to explain the meaning, why I asked for sources. Nevermind me.

Comment: It's not a summary of the answer, it's a correction of a small mistake in the answer. **Update:** OK, I hope you don't mind, I've just edited the answer to correct the mistake.

Comment: @ruakh I do mind, since the edit is incorrect. The term "reserved" is not a formally defined one, it is also used for keywords etc, which is another story entirely. Also there's "reserved storage" and "reserved for future standardization".

Comment: I see your point, but your rollback is also incorrect, since (as your answer shows) there exists "reserved to the implementation for any use", such that "reserved for any use" is not synonymous with "reserved to the implementation".

Answer (score 5):

C has multiple contexts in which a symbol can have a definition:

- The space of macro names,
- The space of formal names of arguments to a macro (this space is specific to each function-like macro),
- The space of ordinary identifiers,
- The space of tag names,
- The space of labels (this space is specific to each function), and
- The space of structure/union members (this space is specific to each struct/union).

What "reserved for any use" means that the user code in a compliant program cannot use<sup>1</sup> symbols that start with an underscore that is followed by an uppercase letter or another underscore in any of the above contexts. Compare with identifiers that start with a single underscore but are followed by a lowercase number or a digit. This falls into the second class of identifiers that start with an underscore. User code *can* can be use these identifiers as the names of macro arguments, as labels, or as the names of structure/union members.

"Reserved for any use" does not mean that the implementation cannot use such symbols. The intent of the reservation is to provide a name space that implementations can freely use without concern that the names defined by the implementation will conflict with the names defined by the user code in a compliant program.

---

<sup>1</sup>The standard does not quite mean "cannot use". The standard encourages the programmatic use of a small number of names that start with a double underscore. For example, a compliant implementation is required to define `__STDC_VERSION__`, `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and `__func__`. The 2011 version of the standard even gives an example of a presumably compliant program that references `__func__`.

Answer (score 2):

The C Standard allows implementations to attach any meaning they see fit to reserved identifiers.  Most implementations will treat unrecognized identifiers of reserved forms the same as any other recognized identifiers when there is no reason to do otherwise, thus allowing something like:

```
#ifdef __ACME_COMPILER
#define near __near
#else
#define near
#endif

int near foo;
```

to declare an identifier `foo` using a `__near` qualifier if the code is being processed in an Acme compiler (which would presumably support such a thing), but also be compatible with other compilers that would not require or benefit from the use of such a directive.  Nothing would forbid a conforming implementation from defining `__ACME_COMPILER` and interpreting `__near` to mean "launch nuclear missiles", but a quality implementation shouldn't go out of its way to break code like the above.  If an implementation doesn't know what `__ACME_COMPILER` is supposed to mean, treating it like any other unknown identifier would allow it to support useful constructs like the above.

Comment: I am well-aware of that. The question was if the wording "reserved for any use" means reserved for any use, or if it means reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @Lundin: I would expect that the maintainers of the Standard would make a reasonable effort to avoid defining names that would conflict with any names that are used by implementations they know about, but I think that's more a matter of common sense than a formally-defined policy.

Answer (score 0):

It is months late but one point remains the others have not addressed.

Your question can be viewed from the opposite direction. The standard allows the implementation (as you have observed) to use a symbol like `_Foo` but, more importantly, thereby forbids the implementation from using `foo`. The latter is reserved for *your* use.

To understand, for discussion's sake, suppose that a future C standard introduced the new keyword `_Foo`. The hypothetical implementation was already using this symbol, so what happens?

Answer:

1. At first, the implementation will not yet have implemented the new standard. Until implemented, the new standard lacks practical effect.
2. Later, *as part of implementing the new standard,* the implementation quietly changes each `_Foo` to `_Bar`.

No problem.

In fact, if you think about it in this manner, you can say that the way the standard reserves such words is almost the only way it could reserve them.