# C typedef underscore aliases in declaration

Tags: c, enums, typedef, pdfium

pdfium's public headers often contain constructs like this

```c
typedef enum _FPDF_DUPLEXTYPE_ {
  DuplexUndefined = 0,
  Simplex,
  DuplexFlipShortEdge,
  DuplexFlipLongEdge
} FPDF_DUPLEXTYPE;

typedef struct _FS_MATRIX_ {
  float a;
  float b;
  float c;
  float d;
  float e;
  float f;
} FS_MATRIX;

typedef struct FPDF_BSTR_ {
  char* str;
  int len;
} FPDF_BSTR;
```

Contrast this to, e.g.

```c
typedef enum {
  FPDF_RENDERERTYPE_AGG = 0,
  FPDF_RENDERERTYPE_SKIA = 1,
} FPDF_RENDERER_TYPE;
```

where the underscore alias is omitted.

What's the point of the underscore aliases, like `_FPDF_DUPLEXTYPE_` ?
(Note: I'm not a C developer, just reading the headers and trying to understand why this is done.)

Comment: Please take some time to read about [reserved identifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers) in C. Identifiers beginning with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter are reserved. The code you're reading is not something you should use as an example of good code.

Comment: As for what the underscore itself means, it doesn't mean anything special. It seems to be just a (bad) naming convention. And considering that symbols in all upper-case are commonly used for preprocessor macros, there seems to be quite a lot of bad naming conventions used in that code.

Comment: Or do you wonder why there's an enumeration tag at all when the code defines type-aliases for the enumerations? Then no-one but the author can really answer that. Take for example this simple enumeration and alias definition: `typedef enum foo { bar } hello;` that's really equivalent to `enum foo { bar }: typedef enum foo hello;` There's nothing special with the tag names, they can be dropped: `typedef enum { bar } hello;`. You really have to ask the author.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But why define the alias if it's not to be used by the caller? E.g. you'd never use `_FPDF_DUPLEXTYPE_`, but only `FPDF_DUPLEXTYPE`.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's what I was wondering about.

Comment: One hypothesis is they are doing it habitually in case they need to refer to the structure or enumeration using a tag and do not want the tag name to be in the regular name space where the user of their headers might use it inadvertently. E.g., if a structure needed to contain a pointer to its own type, a tag is useful, as in `typedef struct _privateFoo { struct _privateFoo *link; float a, b, c; } Foo;`. Unfortunately, they are treading on the reserved namespace, which is hazardous albeit not forbidden. Use a product name would be safer, as in `struct PDFium_Private_FS_Matrix`.

Comment: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69084726/995714), [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/995714)

Comment: I guess I had better raise this on pdfium's mailing list, but I'm not sure if they answer to such questions...

Answer (score -1):

1. Identifiers in C atrting with `_` are reserved and must not e used.
2. They are not `alisses` but tags.
3. ALL CAPITAL IDENTIFIES USUALY ARE USED IN MACRODEFINITIONS
4. Tags are used in struct declarations or in forward declarations.

Example:

```
typedef struct SomeStruct {
  float a;
  float b;
  float c;
  float d;
  float e;
  float f;
  struct FS_MATRIX *next;
} SomeStruct;


typedef enum enum1 enum1;

typedef struct struct1 struct1;

struct struct1
{
    enum1 *e1;
    struct1 *s1;
};
```

Comment: Any comment silent DVter?

Comment: I have not voted yet, but potential issues include: (a) In changing away from reserved names, you have used common names that could conflict with others in the program, which is something that library headers need to avoid. (b) There are several typos affecting quality. (c) “Identifiers in C atrting with `_` are reserved” is not strictly true; identifiers with `_` not followed by a capital letter or `_` may be used other than at file scope. (d) “must not e used” is not the correct rule for reserved identifiers.

Comment: (e) An alias is a second name for something, and the types shown have two names, such as `struct _FS_MATRIX_` for `FS_MATRIX`, so it is reasonable to call it an alias. It is not a formal term with a technical meaning in the C standard and may be used in its ordinary English meaning. (f) Re “ALL CAPITAL IDENTIFIES USUALY ARE USED IN MACRODEFINITIONS”: It is 1970.

Comment: (g) Re “Tags are used in struct declarations or in forward declarations”: Tags may be used with structure, union, or enumeration declarations. There is a particular relevance for forward declarations with them but presenting that as “in struct declarations or in forward declarations” misleadingly suggests some equivalence there. (h) The reasons the code in the sample is written as it is are not given. In particular, the `typedef struct SomeStruct` with `struct FS_MATRIX *next;` looks like a mistake.

Comment: (i) `typedef enum enum1 enum1;` violates the constraint in C 2018 6.7.2.3 3: “A type specifier of the form `enum` *identifier* without an enumerator list shall only appear after the type it specifies is complete.”