# When was random() introduced in C and why does standard 89 not recognise it?

Tags: c, random, std, c89

I’m working on a Operating Systems project with requirements being the usage of C89 and pedantic flags.

Since I am on macOS, I’ve encountered a fair amount of issues with the `rand()` function during a few exercises. In fact, its macOS man page calls it a “bad number generator”. So, to avoid issues with it I had switched to using `random()`. Now, since I am compiling with `-std=c89`, `-pedantic`, `wall` and `werror`, it refuses to function correctly due to having a warning about an implicit declaration for `random()`. If I remove `werror`, it does generate the warning, but it compiles (as expected) but more interestingly, it works perfectly fine. It generates a number as expected. What am I doing wrong? Does C89 support `random` or not? What am I supposed to include that’ll make the warning go away? The man page mentions nothing other than `stdlib.h` which is included.

A viable alternative as mentioned by the manpage, would be `arc4random()`, however I am pretty sure it doesn't exist cross-platform.

My test snippet is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int test;
srandom(5);

    test = random() % 190;
    printf("Hello World %d\n", test);
    
    return 0;

}
```

And it generates the following output:

```
main.c:15:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘srandom’; did you mean ‘srand’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   15 |     srandom(5);
      |     ^~~~~~~
      |     srand
main.c:17:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘random’; did you mean ‘rand’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   17 |     test = random() % 190;
      |            ^~~~~~
      |            rand
Hello World 115
```

Comment: `random` and `srandom` are not part of the C Standard, though they are (I think) in the POSIX Standard.  Try using `rand` and `srand`, instead (the standard C functions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `random` and `srandom` are not part of the C standard. They are POSIX functions, so compiling
with `-std=c89` doesn't make their prototypes available when you compile.

You can define one of the following at the top of your source file to make their prototypes available:

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
```

or

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
```

This enables POSIX as well as other extensions. Check out [feature test macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) for details on these macros.

Comment: Thank you! That solves it. Since I am also required to add a define for _GNU_SOURCE, do these conflict with each other?

Comment: There's no conflict as such. `_GNU_SOURCE` would enable the same functionality as either of these two plus a lot more. So if you're going to use it, then you wouldn't need either of these.

Answer (score 1):

> Does C89 support random or not?

It does not.

> Now, since I am compiling with -std=c89, -pedantic, wall and werror, it refuses to function correctly due to having a warning about an implicit declaration for random().

That's because when you enter strictly conforming mode, the compiler will not allow the incredibly stupid practice of placing non-standard functions inside standard libraries. As described in the accepted answer of [Is a compiler allowed to add functions to standard headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270324/is-a-compiler-allowed-to-add-functions-to-standard-headers) a conforming implementation is not allowed to spew out identifiers that may collide with the application ("affect the behavior of a strictly conforming program").

The root of the problem is POSIX, which is a broken standard not harmonised with ISO 9899.

Comment: Which came first: POSIX or C89?  If POSIX contains functions that aren't present in C89, whose fault is that?

Comment: @supercat You mean that POSIX has not been maintained since 1988 and that it doesn't even list ISO 9899 as a normative reference? Either it is horrible crap which has not been maintained for 34 years or it is horrible crap ignoring its own listed normative references. Which kind of crap is it?

Comment: The C89 Standard, which was published after POSIX, implies that conforming C implementations should be made incompatible with existing POSIX programs.  It would be possible to make the C Standard allow POSIX compatibility, but not possible to modify the POSIX standard in a manner which would be compatible with existing POSIX programs and the Standard's intention to forbid such compatibility.  Besides, many things which are well designed can serve their intended purposes essentially indefinitely without need for compatbility-breaking updates.  Even if newer versions of POSIX would be needed...

Comment: ...to accomplish things that wouldn't have been imaginable in 1988, that doesn't mean that programs that don't need to do anything which wasn't provided for in the 1988 standard shouldn't be able to work equally well under old or new versions of the Standard.  If one reviews a transition between defined behavior and UB as a breaking change, the C Standard is rife with gratuitous breaking changes.

Comment: If the C89 Standard had specified that implementations may behave as though additional non-reserved-form symbols are defined *except* in contexts where preprocessor macro `__STDC_NO_SYMBOLS_BEYOND` is defined with an integer in the range 1 to 89 and nothing else has been done to invite such definitions, that would have avoided breaking any existing programs on existing implementations, while still allowing programmers to write programs that can be guaranteed free of symbol conflicts.

Comment: @supercat The thing is, POSIX was based on a bunch of Unix programmers sitting down and saying "hey what if we could make our way of programming the standard way and then show that down everyone's throats?". _That_ was the motivation for developing POSIX, not portability and certainly not code quality. The majority of functions included in POSIX had well-documented flaws even back in the 1980s.

Comment: But instead of insisting on only including good functions with safe and easy to use API, they just picked a bunch of existing, more or less broken Unix functions more or less at a whim and said "this is standard now, deal with it". The C standard library had its functions picked in a similar, irrational fashion.

Comment: Neither POSIX nor the Standard C Library was particularly well designed, but the former could at least serve as a model for how code which requires some traits of Unix systems can run interchangeably on systems that share those traits.  Much of the role POSIX served in that regard could and should have been served by the C Standard, if the authors had been willing to recognize optional features with the principle "either support some construct with Standard-defined semantics and define a macro indicating such support, or not, but don't define the macro unless the construct is supported".

Comment: I've written C code for TI DSPs, where `char` and `int` were both 16 bits, but I think it would be far more useful to describe that dialect as "C, but with 16 bit char", than to pretend that there's any doubt about the size of `char` when it isn't specified.  Unfortunately, the C Standard generally goes out of its way to say anything about things that implementations should do a certain way *absent any particular reason to do otherwise*, unless the fraction of implementations that should do them that way is somewhere between about 10 and 90 percent.  Since 99%+ of implementations should...

Comment: ...use 8-bit `char`, suggesting that as a "normal" size would imply that implementations where `char` isn't 8 bits should be viewed as "abnormal".  I think it would be far more useful to recognize the existence of systems which use other character sizes, and will often require special accommodation by programmers *whose code will be called upon to run on such systems*, than to pretend that programs are just as likely to run on systems where `char` is 13 bits as on systems where it is 8.